# How to login external web site from asp.net web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, httpwebrequest

I want to login a external web site which is made in ASP.net. i will supply correct username and password for external web site. i does not wan to show the external web side login page. I just want to supply login info from my web page and after login the external web site information will be display in my web site like this image.[image]

Comment: Can you expand on this question a bit? Does the website you're logging into expect the username and password as POST data? If you format the URL to contain the username and password will the website accept it? Is this an AJAX call or is this happening all in C# code?

Comment: I just tried this using HttpRequest Class but i Can`t.

Comment: You mean like Phishing?

Comment: @Vero009, `I can't` is not a very precise problem description. Could you elaborate further what exactly have you tried. And don't say `I just tried using HttpRequest class`. Show how you tried using it. Explain the results of your efforts. Also provide more details about what authentication mechanism does the remote site use. How does it track authenticated users?

Comment: @Hari I can think of one, but lets see what is said first ha - I can think of more illicit purposes though. Screen scraping anyone?

Comment: Adam - by asking the user for credentials on a fake login page, then proxing all conversation between the two sites? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, most web sites will prevent this type of thing.  It is considered a cross site request forgery. You can read more about it here and if you still want to do it, at least you will know what you are getting into.

Be safe.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: This isn't really CSRF since you aren't (assuming they don't have evil intentions) proxying a request through a victim. The OP said in this case they have the valid login/password and simply want to display information, not rely on an existing session between the victim and server. this doesnt mean 100% you cant do csrf like this. But it wouldnt fit in to the traditional realm of csrf and could indeed be legitimate, especially for a partner site that doesn't show info. Although the technique here is questionable  : )